# Подскажите, как правильно писать "Экскаватор" или "Эскаватор"?

Tags: орфография, этимология

Признаюсь всю жизнь думал, что правильно писать "эскаватор", до такой степени уверен, что даже увидев сейчас это слово на [сайте](https://perevozka24.ru/moskva-50/arenda-spetstehniki-ekskavatory) подумал, что это возможно ошибка. Неужели это слово всегда писалось через "экс.."?

Answer (score 1):

**Орфографический словарь:** экскаватор, -а

Большой толковый словарь:

**ЭКСКАВАТОР**, -а; м. [англ. excavator от лат. **excavo** — долблю, выдалбливаю] Машина для выемки, отвала или погрузки на транспорт грунта, камней и т.п. (применяется при горных, строительных, дорожных и т.п. работах).

**ПРАВОПИСАНИЕ СЛОВ С СОЧЕТАНИЯМИ ЭКС И ЭС**

Правописание слов с сочетаниями ***СК*** и ***КСК*** следует запомнить, предварительно ознакомившись с их происхождением по словарю.

**(1) СОЧЕТАНИЕ ЭКС**

Экскаватор, эксклюзивный (исключительный), экслибрис, эксцентрик – одним из значений латинской приставки **EX (ЭКС)** является выход, извлечение, русские приставки ***ОТ, ИЗ*** являются аналогами EX (легко запомнить!).

**(2) СОЧЕТАНИЕ ЭС**

*Эскалатор, эскалация* – от латинского слова ***scala*** – лестница,

*эскадра, эскадрон, эскадрилья, эскалоп* – буква С входит **в состав корня.**

**(3) ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЕ**

Произношение слов с сочетаниями СК и КСК соответствует их написанию, например, произношение «эскаватор» и «эсклюзивный» без звука К является **ненормативным**; также не допускается вставка **лишнего К** в таких словах, как эскадрилья, эскалация.

**Немного истории**

**Официально идея создания землеройной машины** принадлежит Леонардо да Винчи, он ещё в начале XVI века разработал схему прототипа современного экскаватора-драглайна. Известен набросок чертежа грейфера для землечерпалки, созданный да Винчи в 1500 году, позднее Леонардо принимал участие в прокладке каналов в Миланской долине при помощи своего изобретения.

**Первые землеройные машины** были придуманы в Италии в 1420 году для расширения гаваней.

**Отцом первого экскаватора** на паровом двигателе стал 23-летний американец Уильям Отис. Увы, проектная документация и сам прототип стали жертвой пожара, и патент на свой продукт он получил не в 1836, а в 1839 году. **Именно этот год считается годом появления экскаватора.** Назвали это чудо техники **«лопатой Отиса»** и использовали ее повсеместно: правда, только в Америке – европейцы к изобретению отнеслись скептически.

**Начало экскаваторостроения в России** относится к концу XVIII в. В 1809 г. на днепровских разработках песка впервые в мире был изобретен и построен копательный ковш **с ручным приводом**. В 1854 г. в Нижнем Тагиле был сооружен механизм с приводом от **паровой** машины, производивший уборку земли из забоев на горе Высокой.

**В 1843 году царь-батюшка Николай I** решил облагодетельствовать строителей и закупил у Америки четыре паровых экскаватора на рельсовом ходу. Но рабочий класс совершенствования не принял и передал через пять лет машины на стройку западносибирской магистрали.

**По образу и подобию американских экскаваторов** в России первые одноковшовые «землеройки» производить начали в 1902 году на Тверском экскаваторном (в то время Путиловском) заводе. Модель получила название «Путиловец».

Answer (score 1):

> «Экскаватор»… Неужели это слово всегда писалось через "экс.."?

Практически всегда — с момента, когда оно пришло в русский язык из английского (?) ([**ЭКСКАВАТОР**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80&all=x)).

Вот как это слово писалось в 19-м веке [**Глушинский, Иосиф Павлович (1834-1898).
Суэзский канал / [Соч.] И.П. Глушинского. - Санкт-Петербург : тип. Имп. Акад. наук, 1870**]:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое его написание фиксируют и практически все современные словари.

Написал «практически» — потому что ошибки, бывает, пролезают и в словари.

См. «[**Англо-русский универсальный транспортный словарь**](https://www.labirint.ru/books/592886/?ysclid=lozoaodni1518077187)», изданный совсем недавно:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**P.S.**

О возможном произношении этого слова с выпадающим звуком [к] см. **«Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка» под ред. Л.Л. Касаткина**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]